# How can I save the state of a component after navigating to another component in Angular 8

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-ui-router, components, state

I have 2 components: HomeComponent and CityComponent. They do not have any relationship.
After navigating back to the HomeComponent, the state of the CityComponent is lost when I navigate to it again. How can I save the state? Any ideas?

Comment: Keep in localstorage or use store

Comment: Cache your data in  LocalStorage and on ngOnInit()  of component check the data exist in localstorage if so copy the data from there

Comment: @AnsarSamad  the value that I want to save is a boolean. :-(

Comment: @Shikha the value that I want to save is a boolean. :-(

Comment: You can use the route data property

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use services to remember states between routes because they are usually singletons. The state Behaviour Subject can store an object which contains any states you might want to remember for you so every time the component is initialised all you have to do is retrieve the current value by `.getValue()` from the `state$` in the service. Also, when you update any state value you should remember to update the state stored in the service.

#### state.service.ts

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class StateService {
  state$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
}
```

#### city.component.ts

```js
export class CityComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private stateService: StateService) {}
  state: any;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.state = this.stateService.state$.getValue() || {};
  }

  updateFoo(val: any) {
    this.state.foo = val;
    this.stateService.state$.next(state);
  }
```

#### city.component.html

```html
<p>{{state.foo}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Route Resolvers can be used for this purpose

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).